# Pre-calculate attacks in a chess game

Tags: c++, performance, complexity

I'm writing (or at least trying to write) a chess engine in C++. This is the first time I write code in C++, and I use this project to practice.  Anyway, I'm following the general guidelines of a tutorial from YouTube and chess programming wiki page but I'm trying to come with improvements on my own.
At the moment I'm at a stage where I try to pre-calculate all the possible attacks before hand to get better results later in-game. In order to precalculate I use a method called magic bitboards (a kind of hashing technique) and in order to generate the keys I use a dumb brute force algorithm which take relatively long time.
I came up with this solution (with the assistance of others of course) where when the program is running I check if the "magic numbers" were produced already; if yes, then initialise from the file, otherwise generate them now.

Is the way I did it decent?
And if not, what could I do better?

The main goal is to improve the time it takes until the program is ready to start a game.
I'm adding a snippet of the relevant code for review; the entire project (incomplete) is in a [GitHub repo](https://github.com/BAxPI/Chess-Engine).

Here is the part from attack.cpp.
The purpose of this part is to create and initialize possible attacks of the sliding pieces (rook, bishop)

1. generating the attack "on the fly"
2. generating occupancy maps
3. using magic bitboards to hash the attacks.
4. using the magic bitboards to get the attacks in-game with `get_bishop_attack()` & `get_rook_attack()`.

The part I've asked the question for is the part where I generate the magic number which takes the most because it is a simple brute force algorithm.

board.h

```
#ifndef __BOARD__H_
#define __BOARD__H_

#include <stdint.h>
#include <array>
#include <string_view>
#include <string>


enum Color{White, Black, Both};
enum Sliders {rook, bishop};

/* Bit manipulations */
#define get_bit(bit_board, square) ((bit_board) & (1ULL << (square)))
#define set_bit(bit_board, square) ((bit_board) |= (1ULL << (square)))
#define clear_bit(bit_board, square) ((bit_board) &= ~(1ULL << (square)))
int count_bits(uint64_t bitboard);
int get_lsb_index(uint64_t bitboard);


enum squares {
    a8 = 0, b8, c8, d8, e8, f8, g8, h8,
    a7, b7, c7, d7, e7, f7, g7, h7,
    a6, b6, c6, d6, e6, f6, g6, h6,
    a5, b5, c5, d5, e5, f5, g5, h5,
    a4, b4, c4, d4, e4, f4, g4, h4,
    a3, b3, c3, d3, e3, f3, g3, h3,
    a2, b2, c2, d2, e2, f2, g2, h2,
    a1, b1, c1, d1, e1, f1, g1, h1, no_sq = -1
};

constexpr std::array<std::string_view, 64> index_to_square = {
    "a8" , "b8", "c8", "d8", "e8", "f8", "g8", "h8",
    "a7", "b7", "c7", "d7", "e7", "f7", "g7", "h7",
    "a6", "b6", "c6", "d6", "e6", "f6", "g6", "h6",
    "a5", "b5", "c5", "d5", "e5", "f5", "g5", "h5",
    "a4", "b4", "c4", "d4", "e4", "f4", "g4", "h4",
    "a3", "b3", "c3", "d3", "e3", "f3", "g3", "h3",
    "a2", "b2", "c2", "d2", "e2", "f2", "g2", "h2",
    "a1", "b1", "c1", "d1", "e1", "f1", "g1", "h1"
};

class Bitboards{
    public:
        enum Castling {WKS = 1, WQS = 2, BKS = 4, BQS = 8};
        enum Pieces {P, N, B, R, Q, K, p, n, b, r, q, k};

        /*** Constructors ***/
        Bitboards();

        /*** Methods ***/
        void print_board();
        void attacked_squares();
        bool is_square_attacked(int square, Color color);

    private:
        /*** Variables ***/ 
        std::array<uint64_t, 12> bitboards{}; 
        std::array<uint64_t, 3> occ_bitboards{}; 
        static constexpr std::string_view ascii_pieces{"PNBRQKpnbrqk"};
        int en_passant_sq = no_sq;
        int castle;
        int side = Color::White;
        std::string starting_pos{"rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w - - 0 1"};

        /*** Methods ***/
        int piece_to_int(char);
        void parse_fen(std::string); 
};

// Constants masking the A, H, GH and AB files.
constexpr uint64_t NOT_FILE_A = 18374403900871474942UL; 
constexpr uint64_t NOT_FILE_H = 9187201950435737471UL;
constexpr uint64_t NOT_FILE_GH = 4557430888798830399UL;
constexpr uint64_t NOT_FILE_AB = 18229723555195321596UL;


void print_board(uint64_t bit_board);

#endif
```

board.cpp

```
#include "board.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

/****** Constructors ******/
Bitboards::Bitboards(){
    parse_fen(this->starting_pos);
}



void print_board(uint64_t bit_board){
    for (int rank = 0; rank < 8; rank++){
        for (int file = 0; file < 8; file++){
            if (file == 0){
                std::cout << 8 - rank << " ";
            }
            int square = rank * 8 + file;
            std::cout << ((bit_board & (1ULL << square)) ? " 1" : " 0");
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "   a b c d e f g h" << std::endl;

    printf("\n     Bitboard: %lud\n\n", bit_board);
}


int count_bits(uint64_t bitboard){
    int counter = 0;
    while(bitboard){
        counter++;
        bitboard &= bitboard - 1;
    }
    return counter;
}


int get_lsb_index(uint64_t bitboard){
    if (!bitboard) 
        return -1;
    else 
        return count_bits((bitboard & -bitboard) -1);
}


void Bitboards::print_board(){
    for(int rank = 0; rank < 8; rank ++){
        for(int file = 0; file < 8; file++){
            if(file == 0)
                std::cout << 8 - rank << " ";
            int square = rank * 8 + file; 
            bool piece_found = false;
            for(int piece = P; piece <= k; piece++){
                if (this->bitboards[piece] & (1ULL << square)){
                    std::cout << " " << ascii_pieces[piece]; 
                    piece_found = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(!piece_found){
                std::cout << " .";
            }
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "   a b c d e f g h" << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;
    std::cout << "   Side: " << ((this->side == Color::White) ? "White" : "Black") << std::endl;
    std::cout << "   Enpassant: " << ((this->en_passant_sq == no_sq) ? "no" : index_to_square[this->en_passant_sq]) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "   Castling: " << ((this->castle & WKS) ? 'K': '-') << ((this->castle & WQS) ? 'Q': '-') << 
                    ((this->castle & BKS) ? 'k': '-') << ((this->castle & BQS) ? 'q': '-') << std::endl;
}


void Bitboards::parse_fen(std::string fen_string){
    /*** Setting boards && board state to empty ***/ 
    this->bitboards = {};
    this->occ_bitboards = {};
    this->side = Color::White;
    this->en_passant_sq = no_sq;
    this->castle = 0;

    /*** Parsing the pieces location ***/ 
    auto it = fen_string.begin();
    for(int rank = 0; rank < 8; rank++){
        for(int file = 0; file < 8; file++){
            int square = rank * 8 + file;
            if(isalpha(*it)){
                int bb = piece_to_int(*it);
                set_bit(this->bitboards[bb], square);
                std::advance(it, 1);
            }
            if(isdigit(*it)){
                file += (*it - '0');
                // If the square is empty fix shift
                int piece = -1;
                for(int bb_piece = Bitboards::P; bb_piece <= Bitboards::k; bb_piece++){
                    if(get_bit(bitboards[bb_piece],square)){
                        piece = bb_piece;
                    }
                }
                if(piece == -1)
                    file--;

                std::advance(it,1);
            }
            if(*it == '/'){
                std::advance(it,1);
            }
        }
    }

    /*** Parsing board state ***/
    while(isspace(*it))
        std::advance(it,1);
    this->side = (*it == 'w') ? Color::White : Color::Black; // Side to move
    std::advance(it,1);
    while(isspace(*it))
        std::advance(it,1);
    // Getting castling rights
    while(!isspace(*it)){
        switch (*it){
            case 'K':
                this->castle |= WKS; break;
                case 'Q':
                this->castle |= WQS; break;
            case 'k':
                this->castle |= BKS; break;
            case 'q':
                this->castle |= BQS; break;
            case '-': break;
        }
        std::advance(it,1); 
    }
    while(isspace(*it))
        std::advance(it,1);
    if(*it != '-'){
        int f = (*it - 'a');
        int r = 8 - ((*(it+1)) -'0');
        this->en_passant_sq = r * 8 + f;
    }

    /*** Init occupancy boards ***/ 
    for(int piece = P; piece <= K; piece++){
        this->occ_bitboards[White] |= this->bitboards[piece];
        this->occ_bitboards[Both] |= this->bitboards[piece];
    }
    for(int piece = p; piece <= k; piece++){
        this->occ_bitboards[Black] |= this->bitboards[piece];
        this->occ_bitboards[Both] |= this->bitboards[piece];
    }

}



int Bitboards::piece_to_int(char c){
    std::array<std::array<char, 2> ,12> pieces_to_int{
            {{'P', Bitboards::P}, {'N', Bitboards::N},{'B', Bitboards::B},
            {'R', Bitboards::R},{'Q', Bitboards::Q},{'K', Bitboards::K},
            {'p', Bitboards::p},{'n', Bitboards::n},{'b', Bitboards::b},
            {'r', Bitboards::r},{'q', Bitboards::q},{'k', Bitboards::k}}
        };
    for(const auto& piece: pieces_to_int){
        if(piece[0] == c)
            return piece[1];
    }    
    return -1;
}


int get_lsb_index(uint64_t bitboard){
    if (!bitboard) 
        return -1;
    else 
        return count_bits((bitboard & -bitboard) -1);
}
```

attacks.h

```
#ifndef __ATTACKS__H_
#define __ATTACKS__H_

#include <stdint.h>
#include <array>

/****** INITIALIZE ATTACKS ******/
// The engige pre-computes all possible attacks in order to be faster in-game.
// Leaping pieces: pawn, knight, king.
void init_pawn_attack();
void init_knight_attack();
void init_king_attack();

// Sliding pieces: rook, bishop.
void init_magic_numbers();
void init_sliders_attack(Sliders slider);

/****** GETTERS ******/
// Getting the pieces attack in-game.
uint64_t get_pawn_attack(Color color, int square);
uint64_t get_knight_attack(int square);
uint64_t get_king_attack(int square);
uint64_t get_bishop_attack(int square, uint64_t block);
uint64_t get_rook_attack(int square, uint64_t block);
uint64_t get_queen_attack(int square, uint64_t block);

// TESTS
// uint64_t get_bishop_attack_on_the_fly(int square, uint64_t block);
// uint64_t get_bishop_attack(int square, uint64_t block);
#endif
```

attacks.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "board.h"
#include "xorshift_random.h" //XOR32SHIFT Algorithm to create a pseudo random number
#include <istream>
#include <fstream>

/****** LEAPING PIECES ATTACKS ******/

// Leaping pieces precomputed attacks (pawn, knight, king)
static std::array<std::array<uint64_t, 64>, 2> pawn_attack; 
static std::array<uint64_t, 64> knight_attack;
static std::array<uint64_t, 64> king_attack;


static uint64_t get_pawn_attack_mask(Color color, int square){
    uint64_t attack = 0;
    uint64_t bit = 1ULL << square;
    if (color == Color::White){
        attack |= ((bit >> 7) & NOT_FILE_A);
        attack |= ((bit >> 9) & NOT_FILE_H);
    } else {
        attack |= (bit << 7) & NOT_FILE_H;
        attack |= (bit << 9) & NOT_FILE_A;
    }
    return attack;
}


void init_pawn_attack(){
   for(int i = 0; i < 64; i++){
       pawn_attack[Color::White][i] = get_pawn_attack_mask(Color::White, i);
       pawn_attack[Color::Black][i] = get_pawn_attack_mask(Color::Black, i);
   }
}


uint64_t get_pawn_attack(Color color, int square){
    return pawn_attack[color][square];
}


static uint64_t get_knight_attack_mask(int square){
    uint64_t attack = 0UL;
    uint64_t bit = 1ULL << square;
        if ((bit >> 6) & NOT_FILE_AB) attack |= bit >> 6;
        if ((bit >> 10) & NOT_FILE_GH) attack |= bit >> 10;
        if ((bit >> 15) & NOT_FILE_A) attack |= bit >> 15;
        if ((bit >> 17) & NOT_FILE_H) attack |= bit >> 17;
        
        if ((bit << 6) & NOT_FILE_GH) attack |= bit << 6;
        if ((bit << 10) & NOT_FILE_AB) attack |= bit << 10;
        if ((bit << 15) & NOT_FILE_H) attack |= bit << 15;
        if ((bit << 17) & NOT_FILE_A) attack |= bit << 17;

    return attack;
}    


void init_knight_attack(){
   for(int i = 0; i < 64; i++){
       knight_attack[i] = get_knight_attack_mask(i);
   }
}


uint64_t get_knight_attack(int square){
    return knight_attack[square];
}


static uint64_t get_king_attack_mask(int square){
    uint64_t attack = 0UL;
    uint64_t bit = 1ULL << square;
    if ((bit >> 1) & NOT_FILE_H) attack |= bit >> 1;
    if ((bit << 1) & NOT_FILE_A) attack |= bit << 1;
    if ((bit >> 7) & NOT_FILE_A) attack |= bit >> 7;
    if ((bit << 7) & NOT_FILE_H) attack |= bit << 7;
    if ((bit >> 9) & NOT_FILE_H) attack |= bit >> 9;
    if ((bit << 9) & NOT_FILE_A) attack |= bit << 9;
    attack |= bit >> 8;
    attack |= bit << 8;
    return attack;
}


void init_king_attack(){
    for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++){
        king_attack[i] = get_king_attack_mask(i);
    }
}


uint64_t get_king_attack(int square){
    return king_attack[square];
}


/****** SLIDING PIECES ATTACKS ******/

// Sliding pieces precomputed attack, for every possible occupancy.
static std::array<std::array<uint64_t, 512> ,64>bishop_attacks;
static std::array<std::array<uint64_t, 4096> ,64>rook_attacks;

// Magic numbers to get fast access to the sliding pieces attacks
std::array<uint64_t,64> bishop_magic_numbers;
std::array<uint64_t,64> rook_magic_numbers;

// Sliding pieces attack masks
std::array<uint64_t, 64>bishop_masks;
std::array<uint64_t, 64> rook_masks;


// Mapping the number of relevant bits in an occupancy board of bishop attack from each square.
const std::array<int, 64> bishop_relevant_bits = {
    6, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 
    5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
    5, 5, 7, 7, 7, 7, 5, 5, 
    5, 5, 7, 9, 9, 7, 5, 5, 
    5, 5, 7, 9, 9, 7, 5, 5, 
    5, 5, 7, 7, 7, 7, 5, 5, 
    5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
    6, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6
};

// Mapping the number of relevant bits in an occupancy board of rook attack from each square.
const std::array<int, 64> rook_relevant_bits = {
    12, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 12, 
    11, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 
    11, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 
    11, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 
    11, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 
    11, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 
    11, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 
    12, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 12 
};


static uint64_t mask_bishop_occupancy(int square){
    uint64_t occupancy = 0;

    int t_file = square % 8;
    int t_rank = square / 8;

    for(int f = t_file + 1, r = t_rank + 1; f <=6 && r<=6; f++, r++) occupancy |= (1ULL << (r * 8 + f)); 
    for(int f = t_file + 1, r = t_rank - 1; f <=6 && r>=1; f++, r--) occupancy |= (1ULL << (r * 8 + f)); 
    for(int f = t_file - 1, r = t_rank + 1; f >=1 && r<=6; f--, r++) occupancy |= (1ULL << (r * 8 + f)); 
    for(int f = t_file - 1, r = t_rank - 1; f >=1 && r>=1; f--, r--) occupancy |= (1ULL << (r * 8 + f)); 

    return occupancy;
}


static uint64_t get_bishop_attack_on_the_fly(int square, uint64_t block){
    uint64_t attacks = 0;

    int t_file = square % 8;
    int t_rank = square / 8;

    for(int f = t_file + 1, r = t_rank + 1; f <=7 && r<=7; f++, r++){
        attacks |= (1ULL << (r * 8 + f));  
        if(((1ULL << (r * 8 + f)) & block)){
            break;
        }
    } 
    for(int f = t_file + 1, r = t_rank - 1; f <=7 && r>=0; f++, r--){
        attacks |= (1ULL << (r * 8 + f));  
        if(((1ULL << (r * 8 + f)) & block)){
            break;
        }
    }
    for(int f = t_file - 1, r = t_rank + 1; f >=0 && r<=7; f--, r++){
        attacks |= (1ULL << (r * 8 + f));  
        if(((1ULL << (r * 8 + f)) & block)){
            break;
        }
    } 
    for(int f = t_file - 1, r = t_rank - 1; f >=0 && r>=0; f--, r--){
        attacks |= (1ULL << (r * 8 + f));  
        if(((1ULL << (r * 8 + f)) & block)){
            break;
        }
    } 
    return attacks;
}


static uint64_t mask_rook_occupancy(int square){
    uint64_t occupancy = 0;

    int t_file = square % 8;
    int t_rank = square / 8; 

    for(int f = t_file + 1; f <= 6; f++) occupancy |= (1ULL << (t_rank * 8 + f));
    for(int f = t_file - 1; f >= 1; f--) occupancy |= (1ULL << (t_rank * 8 + f));
    for(int r = t_rank + 1; r <= 6; r++) occupancy |= (1ULL << (r * 8 + t_file));
    for(int r = t_rank - 1; r >= 1; r--) occupancy |= (1ULL << (r * 8 + t_file));
    
    return occupancy;
}


static uint64_t get_rook_attack_on_the_fly(int square, uint64_t block){
    uint64_t attacks = 0;
    
    int t_file = square % 8;
    int t_rank = square / 8;
    for(int f = t_file + 1; f <=7; f++){
        attacks |= (1ULL << (t_rank * 8 + f));  
        if(((1ULL << (t_rank * 8 + f)) & block)){
            break;
        }
    } 
    for(int f = t_file - 1; f >= 0 ; f--){
        attacks |= (1ULL << (t_rank * 8 + f));  
        if(((1ULL << (t_rank * 8 + f)) & block)){
            break;
        }
    }
    for(int r = t_rank + 1; r<=7;r++){
        attacks |= (1ULL << (r * 8 + t_file));  
        if(((1ULL << (r * 8 + t_file)) & block)){
            break;
        }
    } 
    for(int r = t_rank - 1; r>=0;r--){
        attacks |= (1ULL << (r * 8 + t_file));  
        if(((1ULL << (r * 8 + t_file)) & block)){
            break;
        }
    }
    return attacks;
}


static uint64_t set_occupanacies(int index, int bits_in_mask, uint64_t attack_mask){
    uint64_t occupancy = 0ULL;
    for (int count = 0; count < bits_in_mask; count++){
        int square = get_lsb_index(attack_mask);
        clear_bit(attack_mask, square);
        if (index & (1 << count))
            occupancy |= (1ULL << square);
    }
    return occupancy;
}


uint64_t generate_magic_number(){
    return get_random_U64_number() & get_random_U64_number() & get_random_U64_number();
}


uint64_t find_magic_number(int square, int relevant_bits, Sliders slider){
    std::array<uint64_t, 4096> occupancies;
    std::array<uint64_t, 4096> attacks;
    std::array<uint64_t, 4096> used_attacks;
    uint64_t attack_mask = (slider == Sliders::bishop) ? mask_bishop_occupancy(square) : mask_rook_occupancy(square);    

    int occupancy_indices = 1 << relevant_bits;

    for(int index = 0; index < occupancy_indices; index ++){
        occupancies[index] = set_occupanacies(index, relevant_bits, attack_mask);
        attacks[index] = (slider == Sliders::bishop) ? get_bishop_attack_on_the_fly(square, occupancies[index]) : get_rook_attack_on_the_fly(square, occupancies[index]);
    }

    // Test magic numbers
    for(int random_count = 0; random_count < 100000000; random_count++){
        uint64_t magic_number = generate_magic_number();
        if(count_bits((attack_mask * magic_number) & 0xFF00000000000000) < 6) continue;

        used_attacks = {};
        int index, fail;

        for(index = 0, fail = 0; !fail && index < occupancy_indices; index++){
            int magic_index = (int)((occupancies[index] * magic_number) >> (64 - relevant_bits));

            if(used_attacks[magic_index] == 0ULL)
                used_attacks[magic_index] = attacks[index];
            else if(used_attacks[magic_index] != attacks[index])
                fail = 1;
        }
        if (!fail)
            return magic_number;
    }
    std::cout << "Magic number failed!" << std::endl;
    return 0ULL;
}


void get_magic_numbers(){
    std::ofstream file("../magic_numbers.txt"); 
    for(int square = 0; square < 64; square++){
        rook_magic_numbers[square] = find_magic_number(square, rook_relevant_bits[square], Sliders::rook);
        file << rook_magic_numbers[square] << std::endl;
    }
    for(int square = 0; square < 64; square++){
        bishop_magic_numbers[square] = find_magic_number(square, bishop_relevant_bits[square], Sliders::bishop);
        file << bishop_magic_numbers[square] << std::endl;
    }
}


void init_magic_numbers(){
    std::ifstream file("../magic_numbers.txt");
    if (!file.is_open()) {
        get_magic_numbers();
        return;
    }
    std::string line;
    for(int i=0; i<64; i++){
        if (std::getline(file, line)) {
            rook_magic_numbers[i] = std::stoull(line);
        }
    }
    for(int i=0; i<64; i++){
        if(std::getline(file, line)) {
            bishop_magic_numbers[i] = std::stoull(line);
        }
    }
    
    file.close();
}


void init_sliders_attack(Sliders slider){
    for(int square = 0; square < 64; square++){
        bishop_masks[square] = mask_bishop_occupancy(square);
        rook_masks[square] = mask_rook_occupancy(square);

        uint64_t attack_mask = (slider == Sliders::bishop) ? bishop_masks[square]  : rook_masks[square];


        int relevant_bits = count_bits(attack_mask);

        uint64_t occupancy_indices = (1 << relevant_bits);

        for(int index = 0; index < occupancy_indices; index++){
            // Rook    
            if(slider == Sliders::rook){
                uint64_t occupancy = set_occupanacies(index, relevant_bits, attack_mask);
                int magic_index = (occupancy * rook_magic_numbers[square]) >> (64 - rook_relevant_bits[square]);
                rook_attacks[square][magic_index] = get_rook_attack_on_the_fly(square, occupancy);
            }        
            // Bishop
            else if(slider == Sliders::bishop){
                uint64_t occupancy = set_occupanacies(index, relevant_bits, attack_mask);
                int magic_index = (occupancy * bishop_magic_numbers[square]) >> (64 - bishop_relevant_bits[square]);
                bishop_attacks[square][magic_index] = get_bishop_attack_on_the_fly(square, occupancy);
            }

        }        
    }
}


uint64_t get_bishop_attack(int square, uint64_t block){
    block &= bishop_masks[square];
    block *= bishop_magic_numbers[square];
    block >>= 64 - bishop_relevant_bits[square];

    return bishop_attacks[square][block];
}


uint64_t get_rook_attack(int square, uint64_t block){
    block &= rook_masks[square];
    block *= rook_magic_numbers[square];
    block >>= 64 - rook_relevant_bits[square];

    return rook_attacks[square][block];
}

uint64_t get_queen_attack(int square ,uint64_t block){
    uint64_t queen_att = 0ULL;
    queen_att |= get_bishop_attack(square, block);
    queen_att |= get_rook_attack(square, block);
    return queen_att;
}
```

Comment: It would be better to pre-calculate as many of these as you can as `constexpr` expressions, and store them as variables in your program. It will be much more efficient to load these from memory than to read and parse them from a text file.

Comment: Next-best, if you cannot make the calculations `constexpr`, is to have a program generate a source file with the results that you can compile and link with your program.

Comment: @Davislor  - I will look into it sound really interesting, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

## General Observations

Overall the code looks a lot more like C than C++. It is actually quite difficult to find the one class that is in use. I was originally going to ask why you don't have any classes in an object oriented language like C++, but there is one class.

When you are developing it is always a good idea to enable as many warning messages as possible when you are compiling. I'm currently compiling the code with C++17 in Visual Studio 2022. I am getting 1 warning message and 3 error messages when I compile:

> board.cpp(18,12): warning C4477: 'printf' : format string '%lu' requires an argument of type 'unsigned long', but variadic argument 1 has type 'uint64_t'
> board.cpp(18,12): message : consider using '%llu' in the format string
> board.cpp(18,12): message : consider using '%Iu' in the format string
> board.cpp(18,12): message : consider using '%I64u' in the format string
> board.cpp(35,39): error C4146: unary minus operator applied to unsigned type, result still unsigned
> board.cpp(38,5): error C2084: function 'int get_lsb_index(uint64_t)' already has a body
> board.cpp(31,5): message : see previous definition of 'get_lsb_index'
> board.cpp(42,39): error C4146: unary minus operator applied to unsigned type, result still unsigned

These are the lines reported:
Line 18     `printf("\n     Bitboard: %lud\n\n", bit_board);`
Line 34         `return count_bits((bitboard & -bitboard) - 1);`
Line 41         `return count_bits((bitboard & -bitboard) - 1);`
Line 37 `int get_lsb_index(uint64_t bitboard) {`

*Please note that the line number are based on the updated versions of the `board.h` and `board.cpp` files below.*

I have done as much of a review as I can at this time, there is room for others to review the code. I would suggest that you make some edits and post a follow up question with a link back to this question.

## Don't Mix C Language and C++ Language Input and Output

While the code is primarily using C++ IO, there is at least one `printf()` statement in the code, this may have side effects that you don't expect. There are ways to format output to std::cout. The Google search `c++ format output` will help you find this.

## Put Classes in Their Own Files

The convention in C++ programming is that classes such as `Bitboards` should have their own header and source files. In this case it would be `Bitboards.h` and `Bitboards.cpp`. This allows the classes to be reused as necessary, and eases the creation and maintenance of the classes.

It makes it much easier to understand and maintain the code because there is less unrelated code in the files.

Bitboards.h:

```
#ifndef BITBOARDS_H_
#define BITBOARDS_H_

#include "board.h"

class Bitboards {
public:
    enum Castling { WKS = 1, WQS = 2, BKS = 4, BQS = 8 };
    enum Pieces { P, N, B, R, Q, K, p, n, b, r, q, k };

    /*** Constructors ***/
    Bitboards();

    /*** Methods ***/
    void print_board();
    void attacked_squares();
    bool is_square_attacked(int square, Color color);

private:
    /*** Variables ***/
    std::array<uint64_t, 12> bitboards{};
    std::array<uint64_t, 3> occ_bitboards{};
    static constexpr std::string_view ascii_pieces{ "PNBRQKpnbrqk" };
    int en_passant_sq = no_sq;
    int castle;
    int side = Color::White;
    std::string starting_pos{ "rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w - - 0 1" };

    /*** Methods ***/
    int piece_to_int(char);
    void parse_fen(std::string);
};

#endif
```

Bitboards.cpp

```
#include "Bitboards.h"
#include <iostream>

/****** Constructors ******/
Bitboards::Bitboards() {
    parse_fen(this->starting_pos);
}

void Bitboards::print_board() {
    for (int rank = 0; rank < 8; rank++) {
        for (int file = 0; file < 8; file++) {
            if (file == 0)
                std::cout << 8 - rank << " ";
            int square = rank * 8 + file;
            bool piece_found = false;
            for (int piece = P; piece <= k; piece++) {
                if (this->bitboards[piece] & (1ULL << square)) {
                    std::cout << " " << ascii_pieces[piece];
                    piece_found = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!piece_found) {
                std::cout << " .";
            }
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "   a b c d e f g h" << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;
    std::cout << "   Side: " << ((this->side == Color::White) ? "White" : "Black") << std::endl;
    std::cout << "   Enpassant: " << ((this->en_passant_sq == no_sq) ? "no" : index_to_square[this->en_passant_sq]) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "   Castling: " << ((this->castle & WKS) ? 'K' : '-') << ((this->castle & WQS) ? 'Q' : '-') <<
        ((this->castle & BKS) ? 'k' : '-') << ((this->castle & BQS) ? 'q' : '-') << std::endl;
}


void Bitboards::parse_fen(std::string fen_string) {
    /*** Setting boards && board state to empty ***/
    this->bitboards = {};
    this->occ_bitboards = {};
    this->side = Color::White;
    this->en_passant_sq = no_sq;
    this->castle = 0;

    /*** Parsing the pieces location ***/
    auto it = fen_string.begin();
    for (int rank = 0; rank < 8; rank++) {
        for (int file = 0; file < 8; file++) {
            int square = rank * 8 + file;
            if (isalpha(*it)) {
                int bb = piece_to_int(*it);
                set_bit(this->bitboards[bb], square);
                std::advance(it, 1);
            }
            if (isdigit(*it)) {
                file += (*it - '0');
                // If the square is empty fix shift
                int piece = -1;
                for (int bb_piece = Bitboards::P; bb_piece <= Bitboards::k; bb_piece++) {
                    if (get_bit(bitboards[bb_piece], square)) {
                        piece = bb_piece;
                    }
                }
                if (piece == -1)
                    file--;

                std::advance(it, 1);
            }
            if (*it == '/') {
                std::advance(it, 1);
            }
        }
    }

    /*** Parsing board state ***/
    while (isspace(*it))
        std::advance(it, 1);
    this->side = (*it == 'w') ? Color::White : Color::Black; // Side to move
    std::advance(it, 1);
    while (isspace(*it))
        std::advance(it, 1);
    // Getting castling rights
    while (!isspace(*it)) {
        switch (*it) {
        case 'K':
            this->castle |= WKS; break;
        case 'Q':
            this->castle |= WQS; break;
        case 'k':
            this->castle |= BKS; break;
        case 'q':
            this->castle |= BQS; break;
        case '-': break;
        }
        std::advance(it, 1);
    }
    while (isspace(*it))
        std::advance(it, 1);
    if (*it != '-') {
        int f = (*it - 'a');
        int r = 8 - ((*(it + 1)) - '0');
        this->en_passant_sq = r * 8 + f;
    }

    /*** Init occupancy boards ***/
    for (int piece = P; piece <= K; piece++) {
        this->occ_bitboards[White] |= this->bitboards[piece];
        this->occ_bitboards[Both] |= this->bitboards[piece];
    }
    for (int piece = p; piece <= k; piece++) {
        this->occ_bitboards[Black] |= this->bitboards[piece];
        this->occ_bitboards[Both] |= this->bitboards[piece];
    }

}

int Bitboards::piece_to_int(char c) {
    std::array<std::array<char, 2>, 12> pieces_to_int{
            {{'P', Bitboards::P}, {'N', Bitboards::N},{'B', Bitboards::B},
            {'R', Bitboards::R},{'Q', Bitboards::Q},{'K', Bitboards::K},
            {'p', Bitboards::p},{'n', Bitboards::n},{'b', Bitboards::b},
            {'r', Bitboards::r},{'q', Bitboards::q},{'k', Bitboards::k}}
    };
    for (const auto& piece : pieces_to_int) {
        if (piece[0] == c)
            return piece[1];
    }
    return -1;
}
```

board.h

```
#ifndef __BOARD__H_
#define __BOARD__H_

#include <stdint.h>
#include <array>
#include <string_view>
#include <string>


enum Color { White, Black, Both };
enum Sliders { rook, bishop };

/* Bit manipulations */
#define get_bit(bit_board, square) ((bit_board) & (1ULL << (square)))
#define set_bit(bit_board, square) ((bit_board) |= (1ULL << (square)))
#define clear_bit(bit_board, square) ((bit_board) &= ~(1ULL << (square)))
int count_bits(uint64_t bitboard);
int get_lsb_index(uint64_t bitboard);


enum squares {
    a8 = 0, b8, c8, d8, e8, f8, g8, h8,
    a7, b7, c7, d7, e7, f7, g7, h7,
    a6, b6, c6, d6, e6, f6, g6, h6,
    a5, b5, c5, d5, e5, f5, g5, h5,
    a4, b4, c4, d4, e4, f4, g4, h4,
    a3, b3, c3, d3, e3, f3, g3, h3,
    a2, b2, c2, d2, e2, f2, g2, h2,
    a1, b1, c1, d1, e1, f1, g1, h1, no_sq = -1
};

constexpr std::array<std::string_view, 64> index_to_square = {
    "a8" , "b8", "c8", "d8", "e8", "f8", "g8", "h8",
    "a7", "b7", "c7", "d7", "e7", "f7", "g7", "h7",
    "a6", "b6", "c6", "d6", "e6", "f6", "g6", "h6",
    "a5", "b5", "c5", "d5", "e5", "f5", "g5", "h5",
    "a4", "b4", "c4", "d4", "e4", "f4", "g4", "h4",
    "a3", "b3", "c3", "d3", "e3", "f3", "g3", "h3",
    "a2", "b2", "c2", "d2", "e2", "f2", "g2", "h2",
    "a1", "b1", "c1", "d1", "e1", "f1", "g1", "h1"
};

// Constants masking the A, H, GH and AB files.
constexpr uint64_t NOT_FILE_A = 18374403900871474942UL;
constexpr uint64_t NOT_FILE_H = 9187201950435737471UL;
constexpr uint64_t NOT_FILE_GH = 4557430888798830399UL;
constexpr uint64_t NOT_FILE_AB = 18229723555195321596UL;


void print_board(uint64_t bit_board);

#endif
```

board.cpp

```
#include "board.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

void print_board(uint64_t bit_board) {
    for (int rank = 0; rank < 8; rank++) {
        for (int file = 0; file < 8; file++) {
            if (file == 0) {
                std::cout << 8 - rank << " ";
            }
            int square = rank * 8 + file;
            std::cout << ((bit_board & (1ULL << square)) ? " 1" : " 0");
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "   a b c d e f g h" << std::endl;

    printf("\n     Bitboard: %lud\n\n", bit_board);
}

int count_bits(uint64_t bitboard) {
    int counter = 0;
    while (bitboard) {
        counter++;
        bitboard &= bitboard - 1;
    }
    return counter;
}

int get_lsb_index(uint64_t bitboard) {
    if (!bitboard)
        return -1;
    else
        return count_bits((bitboard & -bitboard) - 1);
}

int get_lsb_index(uint64_t bitboard) {
    if (!bitboard)
        return -1;
    else
        return count_bits((bitboard & -bitboard) - 1);
}
```

**It now becomes obvious that the function `get_lsb_index()` is defined multiple times (my compiler reported this and that was how I fouind the class Bitboards).**

## The `this` Pointer Is Not Required Within a Member Function in C++

There are multiple places in the code where it references members of the Bitboards class using the `this->` pointer. This is rarely necessary and should be avoided if possible.

Some examples:

```
    std::cout << "   a b c d e f g h" << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;
    std::cout << "   Side: " << ((this->side == Color::White) ? "White" : "Black") << std::endl;
    std::cout << "   Enpassant: " << ((this->en_passant_sq == no_sq) ? "no" : index_to_square[this->en_passant_sq]) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "   Castling: " << ((this->castle & WKS) ? 'K' : '-') << ((this->castle & WQS) ? 'Q' : '-') <<
        ((this->castle & BKS) ? 'k' : '-') << ((this->castle & BQS) ? 'q' : '-') << std::endl;
```

The following code compiles without the `this->` pointer.

```
    std::cout << "   a b c d e f g h" << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;
    std::cout << "   Side: " << ((side == Color::White) ? "White" : "Black") << std::endl;
    std::cout << "   Enpassant: " << ((en_passant_sq == no_sq) ? "no" : index_to_square[en_passant_sq]) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "   Castling: " << ((castle & WKS) ? 'K' : '-') << ((castle & WQS) ? 'Q' : '-') <<
        ((castle & BKS) ? 'k' : '-') << ((castle & BQS) ? 'q' : '-') << std::endl;
```

## Function Complexity

The function `Bitboards::parse_fen()` does too much in one function (is too complex). One of the conventions in programming is that any method, function or procedure that is larger than one screen is too complex to understand and maintain properly. This function is almost 80 lines of code, it shouldn't be more than 50 lines of code based on common screen sizes (maybe up 57 lines). This function can clearly be broken up into at least 2 and probably 3 functions.

One of the major principles of object oriented programming is the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle), which states:

> that every module, class, or function should have responsibility over a single part of the functionality provided by the software, and that responsibility should be entirely encapsulated by that module, class or function.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed comment. 
It is the first time I'm writing a c++ program coming from C so it is affecting me. I will try to review the code several more times and find out how I should do it the c++ way.

I changed all things you mentioned here: mixed output, compiling errors, separate file for class, `this` word and the separated `Bitboards::parse_fen` into 3 shorter 1 task focused functions. 

As for the classes, I don't see what else in the could would be a class so I'll be glad if you have can tell me if you've had something in mind. 

Again, thank you very much!

Comment: @BarAmber There could be a abstract class called pieces with basic methods for each piece, one member could be mask(), another could be attack(), that might get rid of functions such as get_king_attack_mask(). One thing that would greatly improve your comments in the attack.cpp file would be symbolic constants that represent the numbers.

Comment: @BarAmber Your GitHub CMakeList.txt shows a lot of real improvement now. That may be something you want to post for a code review as well.

Comment: So basically something like Class Piece then Classes Sliding pieces/leaping pieces Ineherits from piece? I will try that! 

I didnt get what you meant about the CMakeList.txt, did you mean I should post for a code review only that file?

Comment: C++ is actually a _multi-paradigm_ language; it supports object-oriented design, but also procedural, functional and other architectures.  So classes aren't really _mandatory_ in C++ code - although I agree they are the go-to representation for _this_ problem!